# Como plotar funções multivariadas com várias restrições no plano 3D com o Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: query

Estou cursando cálculo II na UFRN e estou sentindo dificuldade de analisar certas formas no plano 3D e por isso resolvi utilizar-me do Wolfram e sua API para me ajudar nos estudos. Este é um problema de uma lista de exercício:

[image: Q20 Lista de máximo e mínimos]

Gostaria de plotar no site do wolfram usando de uma função para 3DPloting documentada e exemplificada pela própria Wolfram, vocês podem verificar neste [link](http://wolfram.com/xid/0ftul7s-f8oe94).

[image: Exemplo de plotagem do Wolfram]

Minha intuição me levou a colar o input sugerido na própria documentação e no exemplo no site mas não funcionou, só para constar segue o input:

> Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -x^2 - y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
>    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 4], 
>    BoxRatios -> Automatic]

Bem como o output:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Deduzo que o sistema de query do [site](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) não utiliza a semântica da documentação, logo a documentação é para outra aplicação diferente dessa. **Enfim, preciso plotar a função do problema da lista, mas lembrem-se de que preciso plotar com as restrições no plano 3D. E tem mais uma restrição: é que deve ser feito no sistema gratuito do wolfram alpha, não importando quão complexo seja, contando que seja plotado a função como descrito anteriormente.***